# CRM 2011 Creating Case

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We are using CRM 2011 on-Premise. Some of user could not create case and getting error like:
[image]

but these users have right to create and case.

anyone has an idea please share with me.

Comment: can you post here the log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this case entity using any plugins/workflows (which triggers on create of a case record) which is accessing another entity, where these users don't have read/write access.

Hope this helps!!!.

Comment: I am accessing account through oData service but these users have Account Read/Write access

Comment: Can you please post the log information to look at this?